# Sorting a multi-dimentsional associative array of arrays

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array, asort

Like the title sais I have no idea where to start and using asort() and sort() are not helping in the way I thought it would. Essentially I have an array as such:

```
$array = array(
    'array_c' => array(
        'array_b' => (
            array('object' => 'e some Object'),
            array('object' => 'b some Object'),
        ),
        'array_a' => (
            array('object' => 'awesome Object'),
        ),
    ),
    'array_a' => array(
        'array_e' => (
            array('object' => 'e some Object'),
        ),
        'array_a' => (
            array('object' => 'b awesome Object'),
        );
    );
);
```

So I was looking at [asort](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) as I want to keep the associations the same, The function I have started writing is:

```
function sort_me(some_array){
    $new_array = asort(some_array);
    return $new_array;
}
```

this function then takes in $array['array_c'] so that you get back an alphabetically sorted array that looks like:

```
    'array_c' => array(
        'array_a' => (
            array('object' => 'awesome Object'),
        ),
        'array_b' => (
            array('object' => 'b some Object'),
            array('object' => 'e some Object'),
        ),

    ),
```

can some one tell me why my function is not working? Am I misunderstanding the power of asort?

Comment: You want [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) if you want to sort based on the string *keys* ;-)

Comment: really? Hmm ill look into kSort(). I don't think so, according to this it will sort the the key, if you look at my end result the value is alphabetical. I pass in the key to sort its value. Also k sort does nothing as the array remains unsorted.

Comment: This [mcve] is not super clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ksort is the way to go, but ksort does not return a newly sorted array:

http://us.php.net/ksort

it returns a bool -> true if the array could be sorted, otherwise false...

this code snipped should do what you need:

```
ksort($array);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    ksort(value);
    $array[$key]=$value;
}
print_r($array);
```